# Handlebar measurement causes pain

Tags: road-bike, bike-fit

My handlebar size is 40mm. However I tried the a 42mm bar and it was comfortable but the reach is too long. So I changed the bar from 42mm/95mm reach w/80mm stem to a 40mm/75mm reach w/80mm stem. I did not notice a big difference, but I had is pain in my hands.

Is it a problem with the stem length being too short making all the load on my arms?

Comment: Which combination worked for you and why did you change it (or want to change it)? In any case, handlebar positioning is tricky and without photos of you on the bike we can only guess.

Comment: When you are experiencing pain in your position on the bike, a competent bike fitter is an invaluable resource.  If you cannot work it out yourself, seek their help.  Your body will thank you.

Comment: From what you write it seems like you should just go back to the original handlebar that didn't give you pain. Am I missing something? What exactly was the problem you were trying to solve by switching out the handlebars?

Comment: Is the new position also lower than the original?

Answer (score 2):

Anytime you experience pain with your positioning/fit on your bike, if you cannot remedy it through other means, seek the advice of a competent bike fitter. Your local bike shop should be able to direct you to one or more fitters in your area.

If you do not have access to a bike fitter, then the process of resolving your pain could be difficult from a distance. There are many factors in play and without seeing your positioning, both static and while pedaling, will be challenging. I am not saying it is impossible, just not ideal. You may be thinking you are fixing the problem with one adjustment, but ignoring another which may be the true source of the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately a bike fit is unavailable where I live. I changed the 42mm because it was not my size and the reach of the bar was too long, so I replaced it with 40mm w/ shorter reach.